# Excel 2010 VBA embedded word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have Excel 2010 VBA macro which opens embedded word document from "sheet2" and fill "sheet1" selected row cell 1 text into "data1" bookmark inside word document.

Code works perfect until I close Word document manually. If I try to run code again after close, I get empty error message in VBA editor. How to fix this?

```
Sub update_bookmark()

    Dim oRng As Word.Range

    Set objWordTemplate = Sheets("sheet2").OLEObjects("Object 1")
    objWordTemplate.Activate
    objWordTemplate.Object.Application.Visible = True
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("data1").Range
    oRng.Text = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "data1", oRng
lbl_Exit:

End Sub
```

Comment: What line do you get the error message on?

Comment: Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("data1").Range

Comment: Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175181/vba-runtime-error-438